# Putting $scope in Cytoscape click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cytoscape.js

I have created a network graph using Cytoscapejs. I am trying to unhide a div, and load more things after the user click on edge of the graph.

I have the following in my controller:

```
CytoscapeService.getGraph().on('tap', 'edge[id = "123"]', function (event) {

console.log("Hi")
//Above console printout works.

  //The below does not work on index.html
  $scope.testMessage = "Hello World";
  $scope.showMe = function () {
    $scope.show = true;
  }

  $scope.showMe();

});

// This works though.
//$scope.testMessage = "Hi from outside";
```

And in Index.html:

```
<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="container" ng-show="show">

</div>

<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{testMessage}}
</div>
```

The console.log does get print out but the $scope.showMe with function inside isn't being called. However, if I move the scope outside of this clause, into the main clause of the Controller, it works.

Any there alternatives on how I can achieve this?

Comment: any reason why you are not using `ng-click`?

Comment: @Akis, It's because I'm adding an event onto a edge generated by Cytoscape.js library. I know how to add ng-click on an ordinary HTML element such as button but this is a graph generated by a third party library, as such, I do not know how to add an "ng-click" when the nodes/edges are automatically generated.

Comment: if you just `$scope.show = true;` instead of having it in the function?

Comment: Yes, it does. But what I'm trying to do is to unhide a div when a user click an edge of the Cytoscape.js graph. I have added the event correctly following the Cytoscape.js guide. Things like console.log, alert("x") works when the edge is clicked.

Comment: $scope.show = true; does not work as well unfortunately.

Comment: if you console.log($scope.show) what do u get?

Comment: `console.log("BEFORE: "+ $scope.show) //undefined `
`$scope.show = true;`
`console.log("AFTER: "+ $scope.show) // true`

Comment: aha so it gets the value but it wont update the view, updating my answer

Comment: just set scope.show = true; like in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common with angular when you are  using jquery events to update a $scope value. You will have to manually triger a $scope apply:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.show = true;
});
```

Another solution would be to use Angular's `$timeout`

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.show = true;
});
```

See the documentation for [`$scope.apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) and [more scope information](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. Do you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: your scope.showMe function will only run if you call it like that $scope.showMe(); or if you bind it with an `ng-click`

Comment: the function will not be called automatically in your example, you have to call it manually

Comment: I have tried putting $scope.showMe(); inside the event clause, unfortunately it's still not working. It does work with ng-click. But since this is a cytoscapejs graph, I don't think it's possible to tag each nodes/edges with ng-click.

Comment: @ParkTaecyeon can you please update your question and show what have you tried?

Comment: I have updated. I have tried a simple $scope.testMessage as well, it does not work. But it does work if it's outside the event clause.